# Load speeds for responsive mobile web development.

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm gearing up here to take our website and make it fully mobile responsive, thus getting rid of our m. website. I will probably be utilizing Bootstrap.

I've been doing some research and have come across some great resources. Although, I am curious about load speeds and mobile devices.

---

For Example:

Lets say, the desktop version of my website loads in 2 seconds and transfers 3 MB of data.

Now I go on my phone and go to my website. Will the mobile breakpoint version still transfer all 3MB of data to load the page?

I'm not sure how developers go about reducing the request size and improving load times depending on if they are mobile or not.

I assume that if I load my browser and resize it to the mobile breakpoint, it will still use the same resources as the desktop.

I hope my question makes sense. I'm not really sure how to word it.

Let me know!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile browsers will pull down the exact same content as a desktop browser unless you specify otherwise.

You can do things to reduce the page size for mobile, such as pulling down smaller images on mobile. One way of doing this is with the HTML picture tag where you specify different image sizes depending on screen width. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

You may also have javascript that reacts to the screen size, pulling down or reacting to events differently to reduce the bandwidth footprint or make the page seem to load quicker. An example of this is lazy load, lazy load is javascript that pulls down offscreen images after the DOM has loaded.

Here's a great guide on lazy load for page images https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/

Finally, web browsers cache content. So any stylesheets, javascript files or images shared between pages should be stored on the devices cache, this reduces the need for the browser to pull down the same files again and again on each page load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer TidyDev, I did not know about the picture tag and how it can display depending on the width. 

I have looked at lazy loading and caching, I also found some server side stuff that will help depending on the platform.